# How to find SQL Object having the text in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There was some performance issue in my application in production, I did some investigation and found out that one process is blocking my SP execution. I saw the log in SolarWinds DPA and found out that the process having id 12345 is blocking my SP. then it is showing the query in SQL text.

Query which is blocking

```
SELECT ColX, ColY.........
FROM [dbo].[Table1] As T1
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table2] AS T2
ON T1.[PaymentFK] = T2.[PaymentPK]  
WHERE (([Col1] = @p0)  
OR ([ExtBCol1atchFileFK] IS NULL))  
AND ([Col2] = @p1)  
AND ([Col3] = @p2)  
AND (NOT ([Col4] = 1))
```

But not giving object names like SP/View/Trigger/Job. I searched this text in all the SPs/Views/Triggers. But could not find the blocking query.

So is there any way to find out in which object exactly this query is being used?

Comment: That looks like an external call i.e. from your application... not from within an existing object.

Comment: Is this could be in sql job? How to seach for them @DaleK

Comment: It's presumably an ad-hoc job. It looks suspiciously like some kind of ORM like Entity Framework.

Comment: @viveknuna to find commands in SQL job steps:

SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps and see column "command"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help if the script is stored in the database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id), OBJECT_NAME(object_id)
FROM sys.sql_modules (NOLOCK)
WHERE definition LIKE '%search_phrase%'
```